# How to fix "Error: Command errored out with exit status 1"

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am trying to install pybinsim using pip install. First, it was showing an error of some missing build tools of C++ which I downloaded from Microsoft visual studio installer. Now it is showing this error. I am new to all this and I do not know how to solve it.

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python3.8\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ihmza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rtmqzctk\pyfftw\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ihmza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rtmqzctk\pyfftw\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ihmza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-gqwbllud'
       cwd: C:\Users\ihmza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rtmqzctk\pyfftw\

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyfftw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+is+required

Answer (score 0):

Install the visual C++ build tools. The link in the error seems like it's broken, but you can download them here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Note that while the error is calling for vc++ 14.0 - everything will work with newer versions of visual c++.

Try it out

Comment: installed visual C++ build tools, now that issue is solved. Now getting this
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: @HamzaShafiq did you fix it? Same problem here